# UrlGenerationError in rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, rails-routing

I've been tasked with creating custom error pages that fall in line with our application. I found https://wearestac.com/blog/dynamic-error-pages-in-rails which works perfectly fine. I don't get any routing errors and manually testing shows that each page renders correctly.

However, when creating controller specs for the controller used to delegate the routes to the views, I am running into an issue. My views are named `404.html.erb`, `500.html.erb`, `422.html.erb`. They are located in `app/views`. My code is almost exactly the same as what is listed in the link above, however for posterity and clarity, the relevant code is shown below as well as the error message is shown below:

Error message: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"errors", :params=>{:code=>"404"}}`

app/controllers/errors_controller.rb:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render status_code.to_s, status: status_code
  end

  protected

  # get status code from params, default 500 in cases where no error code
  def status_code
    params[:code] || 500
  end
end
```

spec/controllers/errors_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ErrorsController, type: :controller do

    describe '#show' do
      it 'renders the 404 error page when it receives a 404 status code' do
      get :show, params: { code: '404' }
      # ive also tried changing the param passed to redirect_to to error_404 to no effect
      expect(response).to redirect_to(error_404_path)
    end

    it 'renders the 422 error page when it receives a 422 status code' do
      get :show, params: { code: '422' }
      expect(response).to redirect_to(error_422_path)
    end

    it 'renders the 500 error page when it receives a 500 status code' do
      get :show, params: { code: '500' }
      expect(response).to redirect_to(error_500_path)
    end
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb (only the relevant route, our full routes file is gigantic)

```
%w(404 422 500).each do |code|
  get code, to: "errors#show", code: code, as: 'error_' + code
end
```

config/application.rb (only the relevant line, everything else is standard):

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

I have tried expanding the routes so that each was explicitly defined, as well as reverting to the first non-DRY form in the link. I've also tried changing the `redirect_to` call to a `render_template` call, to no effect.

I've scratched my head for days hoping to figure it out but I've had no luck. Again, the route works perfectly fine in development, but when I try to test that these routes work in rspec, it can't find any route.

The error message is the same for each spec in the file, aside from the status code. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to **add :id param** to get method. Show action route is expecting an :id param (url for show action without :id param is actually index action url).

```
get :show, params: { id: 1, code: '422' }
```